# How to use UTC + 6 hrs instead of browser time?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I solved everything so far and my script is working. Because im a real beginner and actually quite happe with what I was able to resolve, some of it with help of you guys, I am at a point where my knowledge isn't enough anymore and I googled the UTC functions in java script but to be honest, I don't understand a word... Now here is the script....

```
     var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
     var time = new Date().getHours();



   if (time >= 00 && time <= 04) {
     $(".open").show();
     $(".closed").hide();
     imgElement.src = "https://www.starhit1fm.com/images/covers/musicnonstop.jpg";
     imgEeight = 70;
     imgElement.width = 70;
     // the image to a container div
     var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
     container.appendChild(imgElement);
     var actshow = "Music Non Stop<br>We get you through the night!"
     document.getElementById("showon").innerHTML=actshow;
    }else if (time >= 05 && time <= 05) {
     $(".open").show();
     $(".closed").hide();
     imgElement.src = "https://www.starhit1fm.com/images/covers/morning.jpg";
     imgEeight = 70;
     imgElement.width = 70;
     // the image to a container div
     var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
     container.appendChild(imgElement);
     var actshow = "Good Moring<br>Program starts at 6 AM"
     document.getElementById("showon").innerHTML=actshow;
    }
```

Since this is for a radio station, its crucial that the shows appear in the browser on realtime. It doesnt help if a user loads the website, he has local 10 am and in my zone its 4 in the morning, the website would show there is a show on, but of course its not. Now to resolve this my idea was: getting the UTC time instead and deduct 6 hrs. and use the result to display, that would be than my time here and it would be independent from the browser. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi. Imho, `new Date().getUTCHours()` could give you a browser location independent time. This time would be the reference in your code.

Comment: Everything related to dates should be handled in UTC time *except what you show to the end user*. You want to only deal with processing dates in UTC. Trust me. Don't convert them to anything until you are formatting for end user display, and convert input date data to UTC as soon as possible. N.B. JS Date objects are exclusively in UTC although they will output localized string representations.

Answer (score 1):

Set your time variable to the following:

```
var time = new Date((new Date()).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})).getHours();
```

Just specify the “timeZone” to the correct one for the offset you need and it should adjust accordingly.

You can find a full list of timezones at the official [IANA website](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Comment: The code doesn't work. This worked for me instead: `new Date((new Date()).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})).getHours()`

Comment: @Renat Oops! Wrote that from my phone and forgot to instantiate a Date object within it to use a reference to convert to locale string. I updated my answer to properly reflect the usage. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: It doesnt work, it just shows /* EOS */. Add it as a function or how? As I said im a bloody beginner... :)

Comment: @AndYman The code I put in my answer would replace the entirety of line 2 in your javascript that you posted in your question. This will set the ``time`` variable to the number of the current hour in the New York timezone. As you didn't post your full source code, I cannot help you pin down where the remaining issues would be, but I will say that in your if conditions for the time (``if (time >= 00 && time <= 04) {`` and ``}else if (time >= 05 && time <= 05) {``) you need to remove the leading "0", as the hours returned by the ``time`` variable does not have a leading "0" for single digits.

Comment: Ok, if i modify like this:
var time = new Date((new Date()).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})).getUTCHours()-6;

Comment: Ok, I replaced and deleted the leading zeros... It works, it shows what it is supposed to show but if i change the time on my computer, like put it two hours ahead, it shows what would be in two hours. The idea is, that, no matter what time or time zone the user is, its supposed to show only regarding to my time zone..

Comment: @JMoodyFWD I changed the script and removed the zeros. The thing is if i put it in like this:

'code'

     var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
     var time = new Date().getUTCHours()-6;
      
        if (time >= 0 && time <= 4) {
'code'

It shows it correct on my website but if I change the time, set a different timezone on computer and/or phone, it should show the content in that UTC time but it shows it in browser time... Any Idea how to fix that? It should only show with the UTC time.